# debian package to ko file

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, drivers

I have downloaded hp-be2net_4.0.359.0-2_all.deb package which is used for NIC driver for linux.

I installed the above package using below command

```
dpkg --install hp-be2net_4.0.359.0-2_all.deb
```

Then Ii have checked whether the package is installed properly?

```
dpkg --list | grep -i "be2net"
ii hp-be2net 4.0.359.0-2
```

How to convert deb to ko file? Because I need be2net.ko file which is the driver for network card . While installing hp-be2net_4 debian package I have not found any .ko file.

`Command output`:

```
/hp-be2net-4.0.359.0
/hp-be2net-4.0.359.0/be_ethtool.c
/hp-be2net-4.0.359.0/be_compat.c
/hp-be2net-4.0.359.0/Makefile
/hp-be2net-4.0.359.0/be_main.c
/hp-be2net-4.0.359.0/be_cmds.c
/hp-be2net-4.0.359.0/be.h
/hp-be2net-4.0.359.0/COPYING
/hp-be2net-4.0.359.0/version.h
/hp-be2net-4.0.359.0/be_compat.h
/hp-be2net-4.0.359.0/be_misc.c
/hp-be2net-4.0.359.0/be_cmds.h
/hp-be2net-4.0.359.0/be_proc.c
/hp-be2net-4.0.359.0/be_hw.h
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/hp-be2net
/usr/share/doc/hp-be2net/copyright
/usr/share/doc/hp-be2net/changelog.Debian.gz
```

> actually our network card was detected with be2net-2.101.205 driver in
>   2.6.32-5.686.while doing the ping to some ip address, reply packet does not come. but we are able to observe the reply as error packet
>   through ifconfig output. So that we planned to upgrade driver .
>   which we saw in the following url
>   [Reference Link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1911673)
>
> please suggest us, if it is there any better idea, if we are doing
>   some thing wrong.

Comment: For my edification can you post the output of `dpkg -L hp-be2net`?  It would be very useful to know what you got in the package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deb file can not be converted to ko file. The deb file is a debian package which is a compressed file containing the package files with the installation instructions. The ko file is a kernel object (module). They are very much different.

However, you should get the needed files if this is really the driver you need. To see the installed files, use the following command:

```
$ sudo dpkg -L hp-be2net
```